# Have 'formatting guide' include reference to code block helpers (Ctrl+K, code block icon)

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

Hi - This spawned as a result of my question,

[Code formatting - tag/block rather than indentation - code block more obvious](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86938/code-formatting-tag-block-rather-than-indentation-code-block-more-obvious/86944)

There's a formatting help page (eg https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) that says to create a code block, indent everything with 4 spaces.

It presents itself as the formatting guide but does not show shortcuts or mention the toolbar icon for code blocks - personally I never knew about those options until I was compelled to write a question on meta.  My guess is there must be others who does the same thing.

Suggestion:

Under 'Code and Preformatted Text' section of `editing-help` page, add the paragraph, "You can use the shortcut Ctrl+K or code block toolbar icon [image] with a block of text selected to indent it automatically".

Comment: +10 really I keep seeing users formatting with _``_ instead of indents, I usually post a comment alerting them about it and then they go aha!

Comment: That feature would be great.