# What is the name of the markdown button bar?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, user-interface

What is the name of the markdown button bar that appears below the Title text box and before the question text box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toolbar? Or editing toolbar, or editor toolbar, or WMD editor toolbar in full.

> - [the Insert Image  toolbar button](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/)
> - [use CSS image sprites for the toolbar buttons](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/page/3/)
> - [click the {} toolbar button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86938/code-formatting-tag-block-rather-than-indentation-code-block-more-obvious/86944#86944)
> - [click the code button in the editing toolbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36993/why-doesnt-stack-overflow-use-html-entities/36994#36994)

Given the Hyperlink, Image and Help buttons, I guess *formatting* toolbar does not really cover it.

Answer (score 0):

Most everyone just calls it WMD if I'm not mistaken.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wmd